# How do I increase PermGen space for Scala compilation under Gradle?

Tags: scala, gradle, permgen

I'm getting `org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileScala'` trying to build my Scala project with Gradle, and if I run Gradle with `--stacktrace` it looks like the culprit is `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`.

I tried forking the compilation task and adding `MaxPermSize` to the forked JVM arguments, but all that did is move the OOME behind an `InvocationTargetException`.

Here's my `build.gradle` block for the `compileScala` task:

```
compileScala {
  options.fork = true
  options.forkOptions.jvmArgs = ['-XX:MaxPermSize=512m']
  scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = [
      "-feature",
      "-language:reflectiveCalls", // used for config structural typing
      "-language:postfixOps"
  ]
}
```

I know I can work around this by increasing PermGen space globally using `$JAVA_OPTIONS`, but I'd prefer a solution that I can check in with the source so that nobody needs to customize anything locally to build the project.

FWIW, I'm using Gradle 1.11 with Scala 2.10.3 under Java 1.6.0_65 on Mac OS 10.9.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it: Even though the [ScalaCompile](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/scala/ScalaCompile.html) task has the `options` property, that property isn't used for Scala compilation; you need to use `scalaCompileOptions` instead. It in turn has its own `forkOptions` property.

```
compileScala {
    scalaCompileOptions.fork = true
    scalaCompileOptions.forkOptions.jvmArgs = ['-XX:MaxPermSize=512m']
    scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = [
        "-feature",
        "-language:reflectiveCalls", // used for config structural typing
        "-language:postfixOps"
    ]
}
```

Comment: `ScalaCompile#options` are the Java compilation options for Scala/Java joint compilation. `javaOptions` would have been a better name.